# No drivers after usr ownership change Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt, sudo, chown

I have Linux Mint 14.2 installed on an IBM T60 ThinkPad.  Everything was going just fine until I was installing some developer tool (I can't even remember which one anymore) and accidentally changed the ownership of my usr folder (where sudo lives).  After finding a way to correct it (booting into the terminal and using the "super root" or whatever to fix it), I have lost all drivers and ability to install them.  That means that Update Manager, Driver Manager (for drivers), and even Synaptic Package Installer seem to have been broken.  In fact, it is to the point where to even connect to the network, I have to do it through Terminal.  I have done so many `sudo apt-get update`s, `sudo apt-get upgrade`s, `sudo apt-get clean`s, and other terminal command fixes that I can't even list them here.  Is there any way to just reinstall all the drivers through Terminal and somehow right what I have wronged?  This is a last-stitch effort, I expect to see a response prompting me to re-install, so that is certainly what I will do if I have to.  My question is whether there is anything else I should try before I do that.  Apologies for the vagueness, please ask for clarification if you need it and I will add specifics as you ask them.

Comment: Before full reinstall, just restoring `/usr` from your backup should be enough. And you can get away with even less if you didn't delete anything and "just" changed ownership/permissions on the files under `/usr`. I would even expect that only `/usr/bin/` should be really a problem and everything should be owned by root, and only 10 or so files need special suid permission: chfn chsh gpasswd lppasswd mtr newgrp passwd pkexec procmail sudo X tracerout6.iputils

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work, just going to reinstall.  Thank you for your help anyways.